# how to map different link in jsp to methods in the controller which extends multiactioncontroller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I m using spring and jsp.in my jsp i am ahving 1 button and 2 links.by clicking the button and link it will perform some function and remain in the same page.so i m using single controller which extends multiactioncontroller.i done the url mapping as

```
  <bean id="urlMapping"    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
<props>                 
<prop key="/adminhomepage.htm">adminHomePageController</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

now i need to map different methods to button and link in the jsp page to perform different actions.anybody help me on this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript like,

```
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="doOnButtonClick();">
```

and for link,

```
<a href="javascript:onLinkClick();">
<script>
function doOnButtonClick(){
document.yourFormName.action="youActionUrl?params";
document.yourFormName.submit();
}

function onLinkClick(){
document.yourFormName.action="youActionUrl?params";
document.yourFormName.submit();
}
<script>
```

this is what I guessing from your need, and you can use annotations to perform different actions accordingly. It will helpful if you provide the source code for jsp and controller.